# Is it possible to consume dotnet angular spa Ideneity API with another platform such as mobile app?

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Used `dotnet new angular -o SPA -au Individual` and got an entire Angular project using dotnet core Indentity framework, I see on the logs there's the endpoints Im touching while browsing the test application.

I would love to consume this using Postman for example in order to map the whole thing and use it in my mobile app in order to help users authenticate using the same account for both platforms and also their data.

I've built an API using Identity 3.1 Core but I really wish to migrate from that project without any GUI to these beatifull scaffolded project that just works out of the box.

Please let me know how can I touch these endpoints

```
info: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      {
        "SubjectId": "anonymous",
        "RequestedScopes": "",
        "PromptMode": "",
        "Raw": {}
        "Endpoint": "Authorize",
        "Scopes": "",
        "Error": "invalid_request",
        "ErrorDescription": "Invalid client_id",
        "Category": "Token",
        "Name": "Token Issued Failure",
        "EventType": "Failure",
        "Id": 2001,
        "ActivityId": "0HM6K6NTM0G45:00000002",
        "TimeStamp": "2021-02-18T17:53:32Z",
        "ProcessId": 8248,
        "LocalIpAddress": "::1:5001",
        "RemoteIpAddress": "::1"
      }
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint for /connect/authorize/callback
info: IdentityServer4.Events.DefaultEventService[0]
      {
        "ClientId": "SPA",
        "ClientName": "SPA",
        "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:5001/authentication/login-callback",
        "Endpoint": "Authorize",
        "SubjectId": "02397ed4-5c90-4652-a1f1-99482bbeceee",
        "Scopes": "SPAAPI openid profile",
        "GrantType": "authorization_code",
        "Tokens": [
          {
            "TokenType": "code",
            "TokenValue": "****09F7"
          }
        ],
        "Category": "Token",
        "Name": "Token Issued Success",
        "EventType": "Success",
        "Id": 2000,
        "ActivityId": "0HM6K6NTM0G47:00000011",
        "TimeStamp": "2021-02-18T18:07:15Z",
        "ProcessId": 8248,
        "LocalIpAddress": "127.0.0.1:5001",
        "RemoteIpAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      }
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token
```

When trying to use this endpoint with postman using the required parameters and the urlencoding it wont work

```
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      client_id is missing or too long
{
        "SubjectId": "anonymous",
        "RequestedScopes": "",
        "PromptMode": "",
        "Raw": {}
      }
fail: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      Request validation failed
```

This is my startup

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SPA.Data;
using SPA.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace SPA
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlite(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The spa contains two parts, the route is configured in configure. How do you configure the identity api, can you share your startup.

Comment: Added the startup.cs file, noticed a video where someone uses this with flutter, will reply if tit works